# How to disable window title update on browser history navigation?

Tags: react-router, electron, react-router-dom

I set the title of my window upon creation and update it as needed depending on the user actions.

However, when using the history navigation function `goBack` and `goForward` (via react-router-dom `useNavigate`) the window's title is updated automatically and takes the value of the title defined in the HTML file loaded by the window. Since I don't have any title defined in my HTML file, it just makes the title disappear.

```js
const appWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   title: app.name,
   webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "../preloads/app.js")
   }
});

appWindow.loadURL(getWindowUrl("index"));
```

**Is there a way to disable this behaviour so the title doesn't update?**
I'm using electron version 17.1.0 and react-router-dom 6.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron's `BrowserWindow` class has the [`"page-title-updated"` event](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-page-title-updated) which has the capability to cancel the update of the native window's title. For example,

```js
window.on ("page-title-updated", (event, title, explicitSet) => {
    e.preventDefault ();
});
```

This will cancel any window title update which originated from within the window's document. Note that you could check for a specific title using the `title` parameter, so as to disallow only some window titles.

As per the documentation linked above, in case the title was created by making the document's URL the window title, `explicitSet` will be `false`.

Note that this will not trigger when you set the window title using Electron's API.